# Trying to find Game App installation folder

Tags: installation, app-data

I used to play this [Bingo Blitz](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=air.com.buffalo_studios.newflashbingo) game and was trying to find where the installation folder is. I couldn't find it under Data folder, even searching the 
keyword "bingo blitz" does not yield anything.

Any experts able to install the game and try to figure out where it is?
My device is not rooted.

Comment: Well, unless your device is rooted you won't find anything within `/data/data`. You could try your SD card for additional files, usually located below `Android/data`.

Answer (score 1):

As @Izzy said, without **root privileges** you cannot see the contents of neither `/data/app` or `/data/data`.

Even if you did have root privileges, searching for `Bingo Blitz` inside an average file manager wouldn't have yield anything. This is because no file or folder is named after the `app label`. In order to turn up some results, in fact, your search term must be an app's `package name`. In your case, the package name is `air.com.buffalo_studios.newflashbingo`.

Armed with this knowledge, we can now say that the app's **APK** can be found inside `/data/app/air.com.buffalo_studios.newflashbingo-x.apk` (pre-Lollipop) or `/data/app/air.com.buffalo_studios.newflashbingo-x/base.apk` (Lollipop and above). In both cases, `x` is a digit depending on how many times you updated the app.

The app's **data**, on the other hand, is to be found inside a folder called `/data/data/air.com.buffalo_studios.newflashbingo/`.